# Assign value from one ng-model to other ng-model

Tags: angularjs

I have two ng-repeat, now I want to add this into my second ng-repeat,
I have written the code below:

```
<ul>
      <li data-ng-repeat="quotTypeOpt in list1">
        <label>{{quotTypeOpt.text}}</label>
        <ul>
          <li data-ng-repeat="quotTyp in quotTypeOpt.list2">
            <div ng-model="quotTyp.value = quotTypeOpt.value"></div>
            <input type="text" ng-model="quotTyp.text" />
            <label>{{quotTyp.value}}</label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

When I add line by this way `ng-model="quotTyp.value = quotTypeOpt.value"`, then error has been occured but need is asign value from quotTypeOpt.value to quotTyp.value

**Error: [ngModel:nonassign] Expression 'quotTyp.value = quotTypeOpt.value' is non-assignable**

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2DlBIvCEXn9jryxsH19v?p=preview)**

Thanks

Comment: You try to do something in the view that doesn't belong there. Why don't you set the value in the controller or a service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to initialize some variable. The best place to do so is [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit).

So in your code, it goes like this :

```
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="quotTypeOpt in list1">
            <label>{{quotTypeOpt.text}}</label>
            <ul>
                <li data-ng-repeat="quotTyp in quotTypeOpt.list2">
                    <div ng-model="quotTyp.value" ng-bind="quotTyp.value = quotTypeOpt.value"></div>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="quotTyp.text" />
                    <label>{{quotTyp.value}}</label>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```